# How do I import DMD in Zenoss mapping?

Tags: python, mysql, solaris, python-2.4, zenoss

I have Solaris 10 + **Zenoss 2.7.0** and I cannot upgrade it without Oracle licence, so I try to find workaround, that's why I ask for your help.

I need to prevent the movement of events into **History Table**, for any event from the same device recieved during the last 5 minutes and then drop event if the count is more then 5.

That's what I try to do (mapping is placed in **/Unknown/linkUp**)

```
try:
    import Globals
    import sys
    from Products.ZenUtils.ZenScriptBase import ZenScriptBase
except Exception as error:
    logging.error('ApplyTestZSB. Cannot import ZenScriptBase: %s\n' % error)
    sys.exit(1)

dmd = None

try:
    dmd = ZenScriptBase(connect=True).dmd
except Exception as error:
    logging.error(
        'ApplyTestDMD. Connection to zenoss dmd failed: %s\n' % error)
    sys.exit(1)

ourMessage = str(getattr(evt, "message"))
ourDevice = str(evt.device)
ourLastTime = float(evt.lastTime)
old_elements = 0

if evt.device and evt.component and evt.eventClass and evt.eventKey:
    ourDedupId = '|'.join(
        [evt.device, evt.component, evt.eventClass, evt.eventKey, ''])

for event in dmd.ZenEventManager.getEventList():
    if (event.lastTime > ourLastTime - 301) and \
        ((ourDedupId in str(event.dedupid) and event.severity > 0) or
         (ourMessage == event.message and ourDevice == event.device)):
        old_elements += event.count

if old_elements > 4:
    evt._action = 'drop'
```

And I have this error in zenhub.log:

```
2013-06-15 21:21:11 ERROR zen.Events: Error transforming EventClassInst linkUp (1)
2013-06-15 21:21:20 ERROR root: ApplyTestDMD. Connection to zenoss dmd failed: 2

2013-06-15 21:21:20 ERROR zen.Events: Error transforming EventClassInst linkUp (1)
2013-06-15 21:21:24 ERROR root: ApplyTestDMD. Connection to zenoss dmd failed: 2

2013-06-15 21:21:24 ERROR zen.Events: Error transforming EventClassInst linkUp (1)
2013-06-15 21:21:28 ERROR root: ApplyTestDMD. Connection to zenoss dmd failed: 2

2013-06-15 21:21:28 ERROR zen.Events: Error transforming EventClassInst linkUp (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove dmd entirely from your script, it is already defined in locals() during the execution of your event transform. There is no need to define it yourself, just like evt is already defined.

To see for yourself, define the following one line event transform, and then use the Event Console add button to add a new event for the Event Class you just created the transform for, to quickly test:

evt.summary = str('dmd' in locals())

You should see a True placed into your event's summary, meaning dmd is already defined, and ready for use :)